# System Information shows my Documents folder using a lot more GB that actual data size represented

Tags: disk-utility, storage, disk-space

Here is the screenshot of the System Information application showing my Documents folder. Documents folder summary is 32.8GB. However data inside is hardly 1GB. There are no other hidden folders.

What is the discrepancy between the ~32Gb total and the ~1Gb of data shown?

[image]

Comment: Which macOS is installed on your Mac? Which program's screenshot does the picture in your post show?